# Is this in an infinite loop? -Coderbyte exercise

Tags: loops, infinite

When I run this it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop, but for the life of me I can't see what's wrong.

The problem I was doing was this: http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Swap%20Case&lan=JavaScript

"Using the JavaScript language, have the function SwapCase(str) take the str parameter and swap the case of each character. For example: if str is "Hello World" the output should be hELLO wORLD. Let numbers and symbols stay the way they are."

```
function SwapCase(str) { 
  // code goes here  
  // loop through, check case with functions isUpper or isLower
  // if isUpper --> .toLowerCase; if isLower --> .toUpperCase
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isUpper(str[i])) 
      str = str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toLowerCase() + str.slice(i);
    else if (isLower(str[i]))
      str = str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i);
  }

  return str;        
}

function isLower(char) {
  var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  for (var j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
    if (char === alphabet[j]) return true;
  }
}
function isUpper(char) {
  var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  for (var k = 0; k < alphabet.length; k++) {
    if (char === alphabet[k]) return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: #1: Is `what` an infinite loop?   
#2: what does your debugger tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Its this line of code:

```
str = str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i);
```

"hello".slice(i) when i = 0 gives you "hello".
Thus after every iteration str becomes h + hello; he + hello. and your string keeps increasing.

One fix is to store the str.length before hand.

```
var strLen = str.length;
for (var i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
```

This will force the loop to run the original length of the string.

OR you can fix via :

```
str = str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toLowerCase() + str.slice(i + 1);
else if (isLower(str[i]))
str = str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1);
```

Notice the str.slice(i + 1);